# Ejemplo de alcance y clausuras en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, variables-globales, scope, clausuras

Estaba buscando información acerca del *alcance y las clausuras (scope y closures)*, y pensaba que ya lo había entendido, cuando veo este ejemplo en la página que estaba la información:

```js
let a = 1;

const function1 = function() {
 console.log(a);
 a = 2;
};
a = 3;

const function2 = function() {
 console.log(a);
};
function1();
function2();
```

Y resulta que no entiendo el código porque el resultado es `3` y `2` respectivamente.

Según había entendido, las variables declaradas con `let` y `const` no se les aplicaba ***[hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)***, así como tampoco a las **expresiones de funciones**, entonces viendo este código, a ninguna declaracion se le aplica *hoisting*, ni las variables ni las *expresines de funciones*.

Según como les expliqué que había entendido, al llegar a la *expresion de funcion* con nombre `function1`, la variable llega con valor `1` y muestra ese valor. Después le cambia el valor con `a = 2` y no se le aplica *hoisting* porque no es una declaración. Al salir de esta función se le asigna el nuevo valor `a = 3`, y no se le aplica *hoisting* porque no es una declaración, y con este valor llega a la *expresión de función* con el nombre `function2` y mostraría `3`.

No sé por qué no muestra `1` y `3` respectivamente.

Dejo el enlace por si quieren verlo:

- Clausuras *(en inglés)*: [jsComplete: JavaScript Closures](https://jscomplete.com/reads/javascript-closures-scopes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es porque en ningún momento entra con `1`. Hasta que no llamas a las funciones todo son asignaciones y carga de información.

Primero le estás diciendo que `a` es `1`.

Luego dices que hay una función que muestra por pantalla `a` y que `a` valdrá `2`, pero no estás diciendo que la función se ejecute, solo estás diciendo cómo debe comportarse.

Después dices que `a` vale `3`, por lo tanto el valor `1` ya se ha perdido. Lo siguiente es otra declaración de una función que imprime `a`.

El problema está en que hasta ahora solo le has dicho a *JavaScript*:

> 1. Tengo una variable que valdrá `1`
> 2. una función que cuando la llamen va a mostrar `a`
>      2.1. y luego su valor será `2`
> 3. Ahora pienso que es mejor cambiar el valor de `a` por `3`
>      3.1. y preparar otra función que muestre el valor que tenga `a`.
> 4. Por último ejecutar todo.

Si sigues los pasos verás que cuando llamas a la función, `a` ya vale `3`, porque las funciones todavía no fueron invocadas, por lo tanto `a` entra en la primera función con el valor `3`. Se imprime y cambia a `2` y se acaba la función. Después hay otra llamada, a la segunda función, y cuando entra, `a` vale `2`, que es la última modificación que se ha hecho a la variable.

Conclusión: La declaración de una función solo la hace cuando se invoca explícitamente, pero no hace que se ejecute.